# Can I evaluate a classifier incrementally?

Tags: classification, model-evaluation

I am training a multiclass classifier (specifically a Random Forest) from consecutively generated data.
It is not a time series, but the data could be seen as subsequent events.
Some of my features access the labels from all previous data.
This makes a cross-validation approach infeasible, because in each fold (apart from the last) I would access labels of previous data that I would not have in practice.

I am considering evaluating the classifier using something similar to the holdout method: 
Say I have 1000 data in my set. I use the first 800 data to train my classifier, and the test it against the data at index 801.
I proceed to train the classifier with 801 data, and test it against the data at index 802. And so on.
I store each classification results to build a confusion matrix that I can then work with as usual.

Is this a good way of evaluating the model?
If not, what would be a good approach given the nature of the data?

Comment: I should probably mention that I have 14 different data sets I can do this with.